# BitBucket Wiki: Create a hierarchy structure?

Tags: wiki, bitbucket

I want to create a hierarchy in my wiki like so:

```
General
FooPages
    Foo1
    Foo2
    Foo3
       ODP
Bar
   Baz
```

I would like to create these pages, and use `<<toc>>` table of contents macros to organize them.

How can I do that? Do I need to clone and edit the wiki on my own machine, or can I do that exclusively through the web interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can (partially) do this, using `<<toc / >>`.
This will create a TOC for all the headers in files in the root directory.
It will not list headers in file in the sub directories, though.
You can do the same for `<<toc FooPages/ >>` etc.

You can do this both through the web interface and locally on your machine.

I placed some TOC examples on this Bitbucket wiki page: http://bitbucket.org/marijnvanderzee/build-wiki/wiki/TocTests. You can view the markup there.

Make sure to balance the equal signs on you headers; e.g. use `== H2 ==` instead of `== H2`.
Both are valid, but at this time, the latter is not recognized by the `<<toc>>` macro.

Comment: Note that in the web interface you can create a sub directory by changing the path when you are in edit mode.

Comment: I so wish this would just work including sub directories. As well as having search functionality across the wiki. But considering the fact that after over two years of asking for something as basic as two factor authentication for bitbucket and still no cigar...

Comment: @Marijn it seems the link is no longer active. Would you have a new link you could update it with? Otherwise it might be best to remove it.

Comment: Hey @Bart thank you for showing interest. I haven't used Bitbucket in years, but I will give it a a try and let you know!

Comment: Sorry @Bart, it looks like I cannot restore this repository. It looks like I cleaned this up some time ago.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the hierarchy side of this question, it's worth clarifying:

You can create a hierarchical structure by using the Title field when you create or edit a wiki page.

Eg: If you want to create a new file Bar.md inside a new Foo directory, just create a new page and in the Title field write "Foo/Bar.md". It will create the directory and the file at the same time.

I'm not sure if there's a way to just create the directory without adding a file to it straight away.

Regarding the TOC half of this question, I found that I can use the `# HeaderTitle` syntax in Markdown pages, and Creole's TOC macro will recognise it.

Comment: Good to know! There probably isn't a way to create an empty directory because the wiki is just a git repo and git doesn't track (empty) directories.